# How do I debug/test URL opening in my swift app

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, url

I am trying to write an app in swift that can be opened with a custom URL scheme. I want to test this functionality by letting my app be launched by opening a URL. How do I debug this in Xcode? Is there a way to simulate URL launching in Xcode?

Edit: It's a macOS app.

Here's my workaround: build the app, copy it into the applications folder so that it registers the URL scheme, open test URL from safari.

Comment: A little code never killed nobody. Please take a look at how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) example.

Comment: But this isn't really a code related issue. I have coded my app to accept launch via URL which I am unable to test because I don't see an option. Whether my code is working (which I don't know yet) is a separate issue.

Comment: could the app be opened from safari?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

OK so after some time experimenting with debug schemes, I have an answer now.
After registering the URL scheme in you info.plist, compile and make sure the app is able to be opened by a URL.

Then go to "edit scheme" > info > "wait for executable to be launched" and then run it from Xcode.
Now if you click a URL, your app will run with Xcode's debugger attached and your breakpoints will hit.

Comment: Man you made my day... Thanks sooooo much :)